# Do you need STP on ProCurve trunks?

Tags: hp-procurve, trunk, stp, spanning-tree

We have 3 switches - a Core Switch, and 2 downstream switches. Each downstream switch has a 3 cable Trunk direct to the core switch.

However - when we disconnected one cable in that trunk group (still leaving 2 physical links in that trunk group online) we lost all connectivity from that switch to the core switch.

Do we need to enable STP?

Comment: Are you sure all three connections in the trunk were being used? Does the same thing happen if you disconnect one of the other cables?

Comment: Yes - if we disconnect any of the cables in that trunk group, that switch can no longer talk to the core switch.

Comment: Please post the outputs of the command `show trunk` from each switch.